# Chrome extension - get Main Text of webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a `Chrome Extension`, and I am interested in getting the main content of a website. For example, I want to get the text of an article, but am not interested in getting the text from the menu. I want this so i can use this text to lt chrome speak.

I literally have no idea how to begin. I would rather not filter using ID's and  tags because those are not consistent enough. What is the best way to do what i want? (It can be chrome-only)

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice is to filter using id's, classes, or tags. Most apps that do something like this have a whitelist of common id's, classes, tags, etc. in use at sites like engadget.com, reddit, etc. If the site uses semantic tags in HTML5, your task is easier, but you can't count on everyone using it.

You are not going to get something that can grab the "article" from any site anywhere. Your only option is to pick certain sites that you'd want to process, manually analyze their markup, and code your app accordingly.

Another thought, you might be able to grab the RSS or atom feed from the site, which will make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the honest answer. I was hoping that google had some API for it or something (since they know how to index webpages). Is there any library where thos whitelists are used that i can implement in my script?

Comment: No publicly available whitelist that I know of, sorry. This is one of the things that semantic tags in HTML5 is supposed to help solve, but it isn't in common use yet.